# 'Smoother' javascript keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, game-development

So I'm making this JetPack JoyRide knock off and I want the sprite to go up when I hold the spacebar, however, there is a lag when I start holding it down it goes up and pauses for a couple of moments, and only then it starts flying up,

```
function playerInput (e)//keydown
{
    //if (e.repeat) return;
     if (e.keyCode == "32")
     {
         if(!(hitTop() || pause))
         {
             player.y -= 10;
            flying = true;
         }
    }
}
function playerInput2(e){//keyup
    if(e.keyCode == "32"){
        if(!pause){
            flying = false;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is the entire JS code:

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
let buffer;
let flying = false;
let player;
let gravity = 5;
let acc = 0.1;
let scrollspeed = 5;
let backx = 0;
let pause = false;
class Player {
    constructor(x, y, imageSource){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.ship = new Image();
        this.ship.src = imageSource;
    }
}
class MovingBack {
    constructor(x, y, imageSource){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.back = new Image();
        this.back.src = imageSource;
    }
}





function initBackground(){
    //set backround color of canvas to gray
    ctx.fillStyle = 'silver';
}

function initElements(){
    //create canvas element
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    //set canvas size
    canvas.width = 1280;
    canvas.height = 720;

    //get context of canvas
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    buffer = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //append canvas to body
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
}

function drawBackground () {
    //decorate your background
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function playerInput (e)//keydown
{
    //if (e.repeat) return;
     if (e.keyCode == "32")
     {
         if(!(hitTop() || pause))
         {
             player.y -= 10;
            flying = true;
         }
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == "27")
    {
        pause = !pause;
        console.log("esc");
    }
}
function playerInput2(e){//keyup
    if(e.keyCode == "32"){
        if(!pause){
            flying = false;
        }
        
    }
}
function hitBottom(){
    let rockbottom = canvas.height - 40;
    if(player.y >= rockbottom){
        player.y = rockbottom;

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        return 0;
    }

}
function hitTop(){
    let top = 0;
    if(player.y <= top){
        player.y = top;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function update(){

    if(!hitBottom() && flying == false)
    {
        
        player.y += gravity * acc;
        acc += 0.03;
    }
    else {
            acc = 0.1;
    }
    backx += scrollspeed;

}
function drawPlayer () {
    //draw player spaceship at current location
    buffer.drawImage(player.ship, player.x-20, player.y, 40, 40)
}


function drawBackground1 (){
    buffer.drawImage(backround1.back, 0 + backx,0, 1280 + backx , 720 ,  0 , 0 , 1280, 720);
}


function draw () {
    //do
//  {


        if(!pause)
        {
            update();
        }
        
        drawBackground();
        drawBackground1();
        
        drawPlayer();

        //drawEnemies();
        
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        
    //}while(pause == false);

}

function init () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', playerInput);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', playerInput2);
    initElements();
    initBackground();
    player = new Player(canvas.width/2, canvas.height-40, "ship.png");//"https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_3969.png");
    backround1 = new MovingBack(0,0, "back1.jpg");
    //start game
    
    draw();
    
    
    
}
```

CCS:

```
canvas {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple animation example</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="game.css">
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <script src="game2.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

</body>
</html>
```

Something Something Something Something

Comment: Could I see your event listener, and your webpage in action?

Comment: `document.addEventListener('keydown', playerInput);`
`document.addEventListener('keyup', playerInput2);`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, so now I know it's not a problem with the event listener. Could I ask what that `pause` is?

Comment: I edited the original post, so the whole code is shown, pause is a bool that changes value when I pressed ESC, I'm pretty sure it's not the reason since it was the same before I added it.

Comment: Can you try not drawing the image? I'm doubtful as to whether that would help, but it's worth a try...

Comment: My friend actually told me the solution, I made a bool value SpacePressed, if (e.keyCode == "32")
  {
   SpacePressed = true;
   
 } and in the update function I put if(SpacePressed)
 {
  if(!(hitTop() || pause))
   {
    player.y -= 10;
    flying = true;
   }
 }
 else if(!SpacePressed)
 {
  if(!pause){
   flying = false;
  }
 }

Comment: Yes, the problem is that keystrokes always have a pause after the first stroke. You can even test this if you longpress a key in your text editor. That's why you need the variable to record if the key is pressed or not.

Answer (score 1):

May just put the position update for flying in the update function. Test it out my self and this works really smooth

```
function update(){
    
        if(!hitBottom() && flying == false)
        {
            
            player.y += gravity * acc; 
            acc += 0.03;
        }
        else {
          player.y += gravity * acc; 
                acc = -0.3;
        }
        backx += scrollspeed;
    
    }
    
    function playerInput (e)//keydown
    {
        //if (e.repeat) return;
         if (e.keyCode == "32")
         {
             if(!(hitTop() || pause || flying))
             {
                //player.y = player.y - 10;
                flying = true;
                console.log("flying")
             }
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == "27")
        {
            pause = !pause;
            console.log("esc");
        }
    }
    function playerInput2(e){//keyup
        if(e.keyCode == "32"){
            if(!pause && flying){
                flying = false;
                console.log("not flying")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the button state in a map

```
const isKeyDown = Array(255).fill(false);
onkeydown = onkeyup = (e) => {
  isKeyDown[e.keyCode] = e.type === "keydown";
};
```

and use that map inside a more consistent interval *(like `requestAnimationFrame`)* to move your character.

```js
const RIGHT = 39;
const LEFT = 37;
const UP = 38;
const DOWN = 40;

const MAX_VELOCITY = 25;
const ACCELLERATION = 2;
const DRAG = .95;
const GRAVITY = 1;
const BOUNCE = .75;

const isKeyDown = Array(255).fill(false);
onkeydown = onkeyup = (e) => {
  isKeyDown[e.keyCode] = e.type === "keydown";
  // so SO doesn't start to scroll around
  e.preventDefault(); 
};

let position = {
  x: innerWidth / 2,
  y: 0
};
let velocity = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

const clamp = (value, min, max) => value > min ? value < max ? value : max : min;

const ball = document.querySelector(".red");

function renderLoop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

  const width = innerWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
  const height = innerHeight - ball.offsetHeight;

  velocity.x = clamp(
    velocity.x * DRAG + (isKeyDown[RIGHT] - isKeyDown[LEFT]) * ACCELLERATION, 
    -MAX_VELOCITY,
    MAX_VELOCITY
  );
  velocity.y = clamp(
    velocity.y * DRAG + GRAVITY + (isKeyDown[DOWN] - isKeyDown[UP]) * ACCELLERATION, 
    -MAX_VELOCITY,
    MAX_VELOCITY
  );

  position.x += velocity.x;
  position.y += velocity.y;

  if (position.x <= 0) {
    position.x = -position.x;
    velocity.x *= -BOUNCE;
  }

  if (position.x >= width) {
    position.x = 2 * width - position.x;
    velocity.x *= -BOUNCE;
  }

  if (position.y <= 0) {
    position.y = -position.y;
    velocity.y *= -BOUNCE;
  }

  if (position.y >= height) {
    position.y = 2 * height - position.y;
    velocity.y *= -BOUNCE;
  }

  ball.style.transform = `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`;
}

renderLoop();
window.focus();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<h1>use Arrow Keys</h1>
```