# move player with in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have decided to create a shooter game using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I created a function that will move the player left to right (horizontally) on the screen. The issue I am encountering is that when I press on the arrow keys nothing happens. I have looked in the internet for advice but nothing helps. The code is at the bottom thank you.

```
<div class="board">
        <div class="shooter">
            <img src="img/cb.png" alt="" class="shooter-img">
        </div>
    </div>  

const player = document.querySelector('.shooter-img');

function moveRight() {
    let rightPosition = window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue('right')
    if(player.style.right === "0px"){
return
    }else {
        let position = parseInt(rightPosition)
        position += 4
        player.style.right = '${position}px'
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    let rightPosition = window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue('right')
    if(player.style.right ==="360px") {
        return
    }else {
        let position = parseInt(rightPosition)
        position -= 4
        player.style.right = '${position}px'
    }
}

function playerMove(event) {
if(event.key === "ArrowRight") {
    event.preventDefault()
    moveRight()
}else if(event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    event.preventDefault()
    moveLeft()
}else if(event.key === " ") {
    event.preventDefault()
    fireBullet()
}
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', playerMove);
```

Comment: Did you try placing breakpoints to see what is happening ? Is it the `moveLeft` and `moveRight` functions that are not getting called or is the CSS applied inside the functions not taking effect ?

Comment: the CSS that I have is this .board .shooter .shooter-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 180px;

Comment: In your CSS you use `left` to position the element, but in your JS you manipulate `right`. besides that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70460950/6567275) I wrote to a related question