# How can I move two objects at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of programming a game in js. Every time I want to drive with one object, the other stops and vice versa the same. I did that with the KeyPress function, but there is also `keyUp` and `KeyDown`. However, I don't know how to do that. Maybe someone could help me.

```
function f_keypress(e) {
    console.log('key press:' + e.keyCode);

    if (e.keyCode == 97) // upper case + lower case
    {
        tank.x = tank.x - 10;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 100) {
        tank.x = tank.x + 10;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 52) // upper case + lower case
    {
        tank2.x = tank2.x - 10;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 54) {
        tank2.x = tank2.x + 10;
    }

    f_draw();

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. You can use `Stack Snippets`.

Comment: I believe your tank and tank2 are using the same reference which is causing the issue you can. You need to create new instances on tanks
Go through https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0
and 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

Comment: You need to manage the keystate, `e.keyCode` will only contain the last button pressed. And you should create a render loop, not trigger render when keydown fires. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70460950/6567275