# Robust keyboard input for WASD

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to check if a key is down each frame.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
```

```
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  const { code } = event;
  keys.code = true;
  ...
const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
  const { code } = event;
  keys.code = false;
```

Doesn't do the trick. The keys get locked up. If you defocus the document then all keys are forgotten. There are various other issues where the keys get locked up or unresponsive.

I'm wondering how to do this in a robust way so that I can do this each frame

```
if(key_care_about_is_down) {
   do_something()
}
```

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70460950/6567275 check the snippet

Comment: Note your code doesn't work. `keys.code = true` sets `keys['code']`, it doesn't set `keys[code]`.

Comment: @Thomas He already has functionally that identical code. The problem is that, when the window loses focus, key handlers don't get called, so your in-memory key state no longer reflects the actual keyboard key state. Buttons get stuck in the wrong state.

Comment: Use requestAnimationFrame(<any function  to run on keyup or down>) that way would be more robust.

Comment: @MilanPanta What do you mean